# d3pie error: no data supplied on d3pie.js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, d3.js

I am using rails, and gathering some data to make pie charts. I am just using ruby objects (so no JSON), and using [d3pie](http://d3pie.org/). First, I make a helper function. Then I make a javascript function using that helper, and pass it in the dom. Here's my code;

**helper.rb**

```
  def options_data_to_d3(options_data)
    d3_data = []
    options_data.each do |key, value|   
      d3_data.push( { label: key.option.as_json, value: value.as_json } )
    end
    return JSON.pretty_generate(d3_data)
  end
```

this takes the ruby hash, and makes it into json

**js function**

```
function dataPieChart(id, data) {  
    var config = {
      "header": {
        "title": {
          "text": "Quiz Questions",
          "fontSize": 18,
          "font": "verdana"
        },
        "size": {
          "canvasHeight": 400,
          "canvasWidth": 500
        },
        "data": {
          "content": data
        },
        "labels": {
          "outer": {
            "pieDistance": 32
          }
        }
      }
    }
    var pie = new d3pie(id, config); 
}
```

**passing into the view**

```
<div id="quizQuestionOptionPie<%= question.id %>"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">dataPieChart("quizQuestionOptionPie<%= question.id %>", <%= raw options_data_to_d3(data[:options]) %>);
</script>
```

when I call a console log in the javascript function to see what data is, I get the correct output that both d3pie and d3 are looking for, yet I am still getting the error
`d3pie error: no data supplied.`

does anyone see something wrong with my code, or something I am missing? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You config option is bracketed incorrectly (everything is a child of "header").  You really meant:

```
var config = {
    "header": {
      "title": {
        "text": "Quiz Questions",
        "fontSize": 18,
        "font": "verdana"
      },
    },
    "size": {
      "canvasHeight": 400,
      "canvasWidth": 500
    },
    "data": {
      "content": data
    },
    "labels": {
      "outer": {
        "pieDistance": 32
      }
    }
  };
```

Comment: awesome, couldnt spot that, and that was the issue. thanks for the help